# Calling an async function in an Angular interceptor class

Tags: angular, rxjs, amazon-cognito, interceptor

I am using AWS Cognito to authenticate users in an Angular app.  I want to automatically refresh the session before it expires each hour.

We set the access token in the header of each request using an Angular interceptor class.  When the user logs in, the time is saved and stored in local storage.  This is checked before every HTTP request, and if the period is greater than one hour,  call the cognito user pool refreshSession function from the amazon-cognito-identity-js library.

This approach however doesn't seem to work to seamlessly refresh the session.  I have been able to refresh the session, but the calls being made return a 401, and it is only after this that the session gets refreshed.

The interceptor looks like this:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const invalid = this.checkSessionNotValidViaStorage();
    if (invalid) {
      return from(this.authenticationService.refreshSessioFromPromise()).pipe(result => {
        const newRequest = this.setHeader(request);
        return next.handle(newRequest);
      });
    } else {
      const newRequest = this.setHeader(request);
      return next.handle(newRequest);
    }
}
```

The authentication service looks like this:

```
refreshSessioFromPromise(): Observable<string> {
    return from((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
      const currentUser = this.getCurrentUser();
      currentUser.getSession((getSessionErr: any, getSessionSession: any) => {
        const refreshToken = getSessionSession.getRefreshToken();
        currentUser.refreshSession(refreshToken, (refreshSessionErr, refreshSessionSession) => {
          if (refreshSessionErr) {
            reject('Cognito: Can not set the credentials:' + refreshSessionErr);
          } else {
            this.setCredentials(refreshSessionSession, this.remember);
            this._credentials = refreshSessionSession;
            resolve('Cognito: refreshed successfully');
          }
        });
      });
    });
}
```

This approach using the RxJs from function is based on [the article by Michael Karén
Michael Karén](https://blog.angularindepth.com/top-10-ways-to-use-interceptors-in-angular-db450f8a62d6).

I have also tried using promises and other RxJs approaches.  It seems like the amazon-cognito-identity-js lib is dropping the async ball, so the big question is how to make sure that the session has been refreshed before allowing any more calls to continue.

Possibly using an interceptor is not the right approach, and there needs to be another layer on top of the HTTP service to accomplish this.

Any help on either the proper RxJs/Angular interceptor way to do this, or another better approach would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in the intercept function. Refactor it like this:

```
from(this.authenticationService.refreshSessioFromPromise()).pipe(
  switchMap(result => {
    const newRequest = this.setHeader(request);
    return next.handle(newRequest);
  })
)
```

The pipe function expects an RxJS operator. In this case we should get the value returned from the auth service's observable and switch to the observable returned by the next.handle call.

Because we are going from one observable to another, we need to use a flattening operator. Promises converted to observables emit a single value and then complete. That means we do not have to worry about a flattening strategy and using a simple `switchMap` will work just fine. If you are curious about other flattening strategies, take a look at `concatMap`, `exhaustMap` and `mergeMap` operators,